# Why my chmod isn't working as expected?

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I want to set my folders permissions to 555 and my files permissions to 554, so I tried the following `chmod`:

```
sudo chmod -R -v ug=rx,o=r,a+X mydir/
```

I thought this would set the `user` and `group` permissions to `r-x` and `others` permission to `r--`, but since there is an `a+X` only folders would receive an `r-x` for the `others` permission, but files would remain `r--`.

But this isn't working and it is setting all the files and folders to 555, even if I set all folders and files to 444 before to assure there isn't any `x` permission anywhere.

**Why this `chmod` command doesn't work as I expected it to?**

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer [here on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod):

When it explains about the `X` option:

> ...It applies execute permissions to directories regardless of their
>   current permissions and applies execute permissions to a file which
>   already has **at least one execute permission bit already set *(either
>   owner, group or other)***...

I really can't understand why anyone would want to apply an `x` permission on any user (owner, group or other) if another user already have this permission already...or in another words, give `others` execute permission if `owner` has it, but someone saw this as the best default behavior and that's how it works, go figure.

I changed my code to:

```
chmod -R ugo=r,a+X,ug+x
```

since order matters, now it will behave as expected.

Comment: Just read `man chmod`, it's all in there...

Comment: I read it, and it says `execute/search only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user (X)`, which I thought it meant only for the same user as this was the only thing that made sense in my head